# What is the kernel of $\exp \colon (\mathbb{R}, +) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, \cdot)$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $\exp \colon (\mathbb{R}, +) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, \cdot)$ be a homomorphism such that $\exp(a+b) = \exp(a)\cdot \exp(b)$.

I think the kernel is $\ker(e^x) = \{0, \{-x, x\}\}$. But I want to know a better way of saying this. I know $0$ is clearly in the kernel since $e^0 = 1$. How can I say that an element and its inverse are in the kernel?

Comment: $x\in \ker(\exp) \iff \exp(x) = 1 \iff x = 0$. $0$ is the only element in the kernel

Comment: In the same way of Jakobian comment.   Let $\phi:G\to H$ be a group homomorphism, the kernel of
$\phi$ is $\ker\phi=\{a\in G|\phi(a)=e_{H}\}$
The kernel of $\phi$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Exp is injective, thus the kernel is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

The kernel of a homomorphism $f$ from $G$ to $G^{'}$ is the set of all elements of $G$ satisfying $$f(g) = 1_{G^{'}}.$$ In other words, it is the set of all elements which are mapped to the identity element of the target group.

In your specific case, the only element of $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ that is mapped to the identity of $(\mathbb{R}, \cdot )$, namely 1, is 0.

Answer (score 1):

> Let $\exp \colon (\mathbb{R}, +) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, \cdot)$ be a homomorphism such that $\exp(a+b) = \exp(a)\cdot \exp(b)$.

That's quite confusing sentence. You use "a homomorphism" which suggests that you mean an arbitrary homomorphism? You also use "$\exp(a+b) = \exp(a)\cdot \exp(b)$" property which actually is a definition of homomorphism (i.e. your "such that" doesn't make much sense). But later you use "$e^x$" so I assume you actually mean "Let $\exp \colon (\mathbb{R}, +) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, \cdot)$ be the exponential map which is a homomorphism".

> I think the kernel is $\ker(e^x) = \{0, \{-x, x\}\}$.

This again doesn't make much sense. How can the kernel be a set containing a set when it is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$? I assume that you actually meant something like $\{0,-x, x\}$ or maybe $\{0\}\cup\{-x, x\}$ (separated in order to index the other set?) which makes more sense **if** you define $x$. Which you haven't done.

You may think that I'm nitpicking or that I'm mean, and to some degree I am. But on the other hand there are so many misunderstandings in this very short question. Or maybe you don't pay attention to details which is equally bad.

> I know $0$ is clearly in the kernel since $e^0 = 1$.

So far so good. You seem to understand what kernel is. So here's the question: what other number satisfies $e^x=1$?

> How can I say that an element and its inverse are in the kernel?

Well, you've just said it. Symbolically you can write "$-\ker(e^x)\subseteq \ker(e^x)$". Or maybe you are asking for a proof? Kernel is a subgroup. So it is always closed under inverses. Or more explicitely $\exp(-x)=1/\exp(x)$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and therefore...?